# How to display a list of items with in view passed from controller.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, razor, lambda

I have this Method that should display The Most Popular/favorite Product and Order By Descending based on the Sum of the Quantity of each product. Although it still needs to be tested. I need to call this method `ProductPop()` from a controller into a View. That is not linked to the Controller

```
public class AnalysisController : Controller
{
    public List<Order_Detail> ProductPop()
    {
        List<Order_Detail> result = new List<Order_Detail>();
        result.GroupBy(l => l.ProductName).Select(cl => new Order_Detail
        {
             ProductName = cl.First().ProductName,
             Quantity = cl.Sum(c => c.Quantity)
        }).OrderByDescending(k=>k.Quantity).ToList();

        return result;
    }
}
```

This is what I have in my View (This view is an empty Index method of another Controller that just returns a View):

```
@using ProjectName.Controllers;
@{
    AnalysisController AC = new AnalysisController();
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@foreach(var od in ProductPop())
{
   <table>
      <tr>
          <th>
              Product Name
          </th>
          <th>
             Quantity
          </th>
      </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               @od.ProductName
           </td>
           <td>
               @od.Quantity
           </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
}
```

If there are any references / Advice. I will Glady appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried to read base ASP.NET MVC tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be creating an instance of your controller like that, but rather pass along a model to your view. You can either pass the `List<Order_Detail>` directly as the model, or wrap that `List<Order_Detail>` in a model like I have in the code sample below.

First, create a new class for your model:

```
public class ProductPopModel {
    public List<Order_Detail> Result { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your `Index` action inside your `Analysis` controller, create a `ProductPopModel` instance a fill it:

```
public class AnalysisController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index() {
        List<Order_Detail> result = new List<Order_Detail>();
        //The code below will never return anything because you are peforming operations on an empty list
        result.GroupBy(l => l.ProductName).Select(cl => new Order_Detail
        {
             ProductName = cl.First().ProductName,
             Quantity = cl.Sum(c => c.Quantity)
        }).OrderByDescending(k=>k.Quantity).ToList();
        var model = new ProductPopModel {
            Result = result
        };

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Please note the comment where I point out that your `result` will always be empty, because you are performing operations `GroupBy`, `Select` on an empty `List<Order_Detail>`.

Then finally, in your view, specify the model type with `@model`:

```
@model ProductPopModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@foreach(var od in Model.Result)
{
   <table>
      <tr>
          <th>
              Product Name
          </th>
          <th>
             Quantity
          </th>
      </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               @od.ProductName
           </td>
           <td>
               @od.Quantity
           </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

return **OrderDetail** data in Index ActionResult  and use `@model` on your view

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View(ProductPop());
}
```

**View**

```
@model Order_Detail;

@foreach(var od in ProductPop())
{
   <table>
      <tr>
          <th>
              Product Name
          </th>
          <th>
             Quantity
          </th>
      </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               @model.ProductName
           </td>
           <td>
               @model.Quantity
           </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
}
```